# Mandelbrot draw method

Tags: c++

I have the assignment to finish a mandelbrot program in C++. I'm not that good in C++, I prefer Java or C# but this has to be done in C++. I got some sample code which I have to finish. I'm trying to put the drawing code in the main (between the works comments) into a method (draw_Mandelbrot). The code in the main method works and gives me a nice mandelbrot image but when I use the draw_Mandelbrot method (and comment the draw code in main) I get a grey rectangle image as output. How can I make the draw_Mandelbrot method work? The code above the draw_Mandelbrot method is all sample code and not created by myself.

```
// mandelbrot.cpp
// compile with: g++ -std=c++11 mandelbrot.cpp -o mandelbrot
// view output with: eog mandelbrot.ppm

#include <fstream>
#include <complex> // if you make use of complex number facilities in C++
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <complex>


using namespace std;

template <class T> struct RGB { T r, g, b; };

template <class T>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(const size_t rows, const size_t cols) : _rows(rows), _cols(cols) {
        _matrix = new T*[rows];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            _matrix[i] = new T[cols];
        }
    }
    Matrix(const Matrix &m) : _rows(m._rows), _cols(m._cols) {
        _matrix = new T*[m._rows];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < m._rows; ++i) {
            _matrix[i] = new T[m._cols];
            for (size_t j = 0; j < m._cols; ++j) {
                _matrix[i][j] = m._matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    ~Matrix() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _rows; ++i) {
            delete [] _matrix[i];
        }
        delete [] _matrix;
    }
    T *operator[] (const size_t nIndex)
    {
        return _matrix[nIndex];
    }
    size_t width() const { return _cols; }
    size_t height() const { return _rows; }
protected:
    size_t _rows, _cols;
    T **_matrix;
};

// Portable PixMap image
class PPMImage : public Matrix<RGB<unsigned char> >
{
public:
    PPMImage(const size_t height, const size_t width) : Matrix(height, width) { }
    void save(const std::string &filename)
    {
        std::ofstream out(filename, std::ios_base::binary);
        out <<"P6" << std::endl << _cols << " " << _rows << std::endl << 255 << std::endl;
        for (size_t y=0; y<_rows; y++)
            for (size_t x=0; x<_cols; x++) 
                out << _matrix[y][x].r << _matrix[y][x].g << _matrix[y][x].b;
    }    
};


void draw_Mandelbrot(PPMImage image, const unsigned width, const unsigned height, double cxmin, double cxmax, double cymin, double cymax,unsigned int max_iterations)                         
{
    for (std::size_t ix = 0; ix < width; ++ix)
        for (std::size_t iy = 0; iy < height; ++iy)
        {
            std::complex<double> c(cxmin + ix / (width - 1.0)*(cxmax - cxmin), cymin + iy / (height - 1.0)*(cymax - cymin));
            std::complex<double> z = 0;
            unsigned int iterations;

            for (iterations = 0; iterations < max_iterations && std::abs(z) < 2.0; ++iterations)
                z = z*z + c;

            image[iy][ix].r = image[iy][ix].g = image[iy][ix].b = iterations;

        }
}

int main()
{
    const unsigned width = 1600;
    const unsigned height = 1600;

    PPMImage image(height, width);


    //image[y][x].r = image[y][x].g = image[y][x].b = 255; // white pixel   
    //image[y][x].r = image[y][x].g = image[y][x][b] = 0; // black pixel
    //image[y][x].r = image[y][x].g = image[y][x].b = 0; // black pixel


    //// red pixel
    //image[y][x].r = 255;
    //image[y][x].g = 0;
    //image[y][x].b = 0;

    draw_Mandelbrot(image, width, height, -2.0, 0.5, -1.0, 1.0, 10);

    //works        

    //double cymin = -1.0;
    //double cymax = 1.0;
    //double cxmin = -2.0;
    //double cxmax = 0.5;
    //unsigned int max_iterations = 100;

    //for (std::size_t ix = 0; ix < width; ++ix)
    //  for (std::size_t iy = 0; iy < height; ++iy)
    //  {
    //      std::complex<double> c(cxmin + ix / (width - 1.0)*(cxmax - cxmin), cymin + iy / (height - 1.0)*(cymax - cymin));
    //      std::complex<double> z = 0;
    //      unsigned int iterations;

    //      for (iterations = 0; iterations < max_iterations && std::abs(z) < 2.0; ++iterations)
    //          z = z*z + c;

    //      image[iy][ix].r = image[iy][ix].g = image[iy][ix].b = iterations; 

    //  }

    //works

    image.save("mandelbrot.ppm");
    return 0;
}
```

Output image when using the code in the main method

[image: mandelbrot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the image by value, so the function works on a separate image to the one in `main`, which is left in its initial state.

Either pass by reference:

```
void draw_Mandelbrot(PPMImage & image, ...)
```

or return a value:

```
PPMImage draw_Mandelbrot(...) {
    PPMImage image(height, width);
    // your code here
    return image;
}

// in main
PPMImage image = draw_Mandelbrot(...);
```